# How do you get the tax value to print without overtime

Tags: python

```
    user = str
end = False
hours = round(40,2)
print("How much do you make?")
while end == False:
  user = input("\nPlease enter your name or type '0' to quit: ")  
  if user == "0":
     print("End of Report")
     break
  else:
     hours = (float(input("Please enter hours worked: ", )))
     payrate =(float(input("Please enter your payrate: $", )))
     taxrate = (float(input ("Please enter tax rate: ")))
  if hours <= 40:
     print(user)
     print("Overtime hours: 0")
     print("Overtime Pay: $0.00")
     regularpay = round(hours * payrate, 2)
     print("Gross Pay: $", regularpay)
  elif hours > 40:
     overtimehours = round(hours - 40.00,2)
     print("Overtime hours: ", overtimehours)
     print("Employee's name: ", user)
     regularpay = round(hours * payrate,2)
     overtimerate = round(payrate * 1.5, 2)
     overtimepay = round(overtimehours * overtimerate)

if overtimepay == 0:
    grosspay = round(regularpay,2)

else overtimepay > 0:
    grosspay = round(regularpay+overtimepay,2)


    income = (grosspay * taxrate)
    print("Regular Pay: $", regularpay)
    print("Overtime Pay: $",overtimepay)
    print("Gross Pay: $", grosspay)
    print ("Income: $", income)
```

I added that extra If/Else statement to hopefully force it it through but that still didnt seem to get it to work. Even if you remove the second else if statement it still does not get it to print, only when you do have over time then it factors in the tax rate.

Comment: `else overtimepay > 0:` is not valid python.  Use `elif`

Comment: that helped it got rid of my syntax error but it still doesnt seem to work, I just completely ignores the tax rate and does not print income

Comment: Please run your code using `pdb` like this: `python -m pdb <filename of your python file>`. Then enter `step`. For each `step` command entered, the Python debugger proceeds one program line. At any point you can print variable values using `print(<varname>)`. This way you should be able to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You only set overtimepay when you actually  process overtime. Undefined variables in python are not 0. They are a special value *None*. Therefore if no overtime was worked, neither of your ifs  evaluates to True and neither branch gets executed.

Comment: That was part of the issue and the other part was because I want printing it as well. But that helped me get thinking on the right track